# Does Citrix XenServer have storage Migration

Tags: storage, migration, citrix, xenserver

I'm trying to find out. I can't seem to find a defenitive yes / no answers so I thought I'd ask the ServerFault community this simple question:

Does XenServer (in any version) support Storage migration such as VMWare's Storage VMotion capability, or Hyper-V's storage migration ?

I'm trying to do a comparative study of all platforms but I can't find a website (preff. Citrix supported or any other "legit" source) where it say's a defenitive yes or no.

Anyone able to answer this one for me ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

There's a bit of a comparison between XenServer and VMware [here](http://www.citrix.com/site/resources/dynamic/salesdocs/xs_vs_vmware_comparison.pdf). Pretty much the same doc [here](http://www.covisia.com/covisia/media/pdfs/citrix/xenserver-hyper-v-vmware-comparison-(customer-distributable).pdf), but with a pretty table, and ticks in boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but new answer... Yes, as of V6.1 it does.